# Redirect Windows boot screen to file

Tags: windows, boot, redirection

I know you can somehow print Windows booting sequence messages, such as loading ntoskrnl.exe, hal.dll and so when Windows is booting without a GUI into file.

I can't find how to do this, any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you restart your computer, press the F8 key until the Windows boot menu shows. It looks slightly different depending on which version of Windows you are using, but essentially use the <kbd>↓</kbd> key to move down to the 'Enable Boot Logging' item. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enable that.

[image: Selecting boot logging]

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to start booting the OS. Once you are in Windows you can open the bootlog in the file `%SYSTEMROOT%\ntbootlog.txt`.

[image: Start the boot process]